# Search for a Word on website and get the next words in return

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, xpath, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm confronted with a challenge, that I can't solve by myself. I try to explain it as good as possible (since I'm a bloody beginner in python and web scraping, this might work not so well, so sorry in advance):

I want to get the text "Herr Max Mustermann" from the website. This text is changing from site to site.
My plan was to search for the word "Position", which is stable from site to site and than get the next words. Is that possible? Since I'm a beginner, I have no clue of the syntax needed or how to search for potential solutions.

Here is an html example:

```
Privatperson
<br>
<strong>Position</strong>
<br>
Herr Max Mustermann
<br>
Privatperson
<br>
```

And here the code written so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from lxml import etree

url = "https://www.firmenabc.at/austrian-airlines-ag_EES"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
dom = etree.HTML(str(soup))
Vorstand = (dom.xpath('//*[text()="Vorstand"]')[0].text)
print(Vorstand)
```

Thanks so much for your support!
Cheers
Peter Silie

Comment: Could you share url of the website?

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [ask], provide the code you have written and get stuck as [mcve], so that everybody could reproduce your issue. Thanks

Comment: If I search `<strong>Position</strong>` in the DevTools it doesn't find anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [string argument](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-string-argument) to search for exact pattern and `.find_next_sibling(string=True)` navigating to your goal:

```
soup.find('strong', string='Vorstand').find_next_sibling(string=True).strip()
```

Or going with `xpath` use `/following-sibling::text()[1]`:

```
dom = etree.HTML(requests.get(url).text)
[s.strip() for s in dom.xpath('//strong[text()="Vorstand"][1]/following-sibling::text()[1]')]
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.firmenabc.at/austrian-airlines-ag_EES"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

soup.find('strong', string='Vorstand').find_next_sibling(string=True).strip()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there is an additional issue. I have described it above as an update.

Comment: To keep original post clean and clear, this would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus -  Simply drop the link to the new question in comments, so everybody has a reference and could take a look. Would be great, thanks

Comment: Sure thing: Here is the link to the additional question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75246393/find-text-with-find-next-sibling-if-it-is-sometimes-hyperlinked-and-sometimes-n